# ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block

Tags: filesystems, partition, data-recovery, sd-card

I'm trying to resize a Linux partition, but after tweaking a lot with this disk I don't know If I have totally corrupted it.

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          64  5913631  5913568  2.8G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdd2        5913632  5915039     1408  704K  1 FAT12
/dev/sdd3        5915040 17578125 11663086  5.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdd4       17578126 28320312 10742187  5.1G 83 Linux
```

Using `dd` deleting partitions and creating new ones I get

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          64  5913631  5913568  2.8G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdd2        5913632  5915039     1408  704K  1 FAT12
/dev/sdd3        5915040 40000000 34084961 16.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdd4       40000001 62521343 22521343 10.8G 83 Linux
```

Then following some tutorial I do

```
 $ e2fsck -f /dev/sdd1
 $ e2fsck 1.43.7 (16-Oct-2017)
 $ ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
 $ e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...


 $ e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd1

 The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
 is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate      superblock:

 e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
  or
 e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

 /dev/sdd1 contains a iso9660 file system labelled 'Kali Live'
```

(And so on for the rest of the next 3 partitions)

Trying to resize makes the same effect:

```
$ resize2fs /dev/sdd3
resize2fs 1.43.7 (16-Oct-2017)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I've followed a tutorial in internet but is not working, titled: [HOWTO: Repair a broken Ext4 Superblock in Ubuntu](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/).

```
 $ mke2fs -n /dev/sdd4

 $ e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sdd4

 $ e2fsck 1.43.7 (16-Oct-2017)
 e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdd4

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

So I definitely run out of ideas of what to do. Is it totally wasted or shall I just reinstall everything from the scratch?

Comment: sdd1 isn't an ext2 filesystem.  it's marked `HPFS/NTFS`, so I'm not surprised that e2fsck doesn't work on that.
For `sdd3` and `sdd4`, you used `dd` to change your partition table?

Comment: Yeah exactly I used dd to change the partition table

Comment: can you show the dd commands you used to alter the partition table?

Comment: disk /dev/sdd
d
4
d
3
n
p
3
5915040 17578125
(Do you want to remove the signature?) N
n 4  40000001 62521343 N w (writting down the changes)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mke2fs` to get the superblock backup:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdaX
```

sample output:

```
Super-block backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000
```

Restart the super-block:

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdaX
```

If the first one doesn't work try the next until you find a working one. Once done interrupt the operation then run:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sdaX
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131621/discussion-on-answer-by-gad3r-ext2fs-open2-bad-magic-number-in-super-block).

Comment: I tried looping through all superblocks using the command below, but it didnt work:
`list="32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544"
IFS=","; for i in $list; do e2fsck -b $i /dev/sda; done`

Comment: @alchemy if you have a new problem, you should ask it separately. That way, you can spell out the situation and errors you get from your system. Comments are not built for new questions. If you think this answer needs to change, then please explain that (not "it didn't work for me").  Thank you!